# what is the proper way of creating curl get request with a content-type application/x-www-form-urlencode using codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Here's my request method. I use `cURL` to get data from requested link.

**get request**

```
<?php

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "",  //URL here
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "msgID=aee68d26fdf847b4bed98b532af15f4b&grabID=7ebd8022-8f85-4986-b8bb-4b65aab03f24&terminalID=1a5bf6d4668e4f31a98bce18c&currency=SGD&txType=P2M&partnerTxID=N71AMM7KGT&undefined=",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: $secret:1ZCiCYXXNnIFM8hKZZxrL8jztk+qNMGq17534bbdqd0=",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2019 01:39:07 GMT",
        "Postman-Token: afc43fd5-0844-4d52-9f6d-f442d6934781",
        "cache-control: no-cache"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {`enter code here`
      echo $response;
    }
```

Can someone enlighten me what can do about it with the use of `cURL`? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is there any error thrown? Or your are getting the data correctly?

Comment: I'm getting unauthorized return. I am just wondering if my request composition for that particular http method and content-type. When create using POST and application/json I got my desired result

Comment: Maybe the method of that request is `POST` not `GET`?

Comment: according to the documentation of the API that I am working with, Its must be GET.

Comment: If I use POST method the return is "no route and no API found with those values".

Comment: Your code works smoothly, I think it is on the Values of `Headers` or `Keys` is incorrect so you are unauthorize to access or get the datas.

Comment: I am sure that keys are not the problem. Regarding the headers I'm not sure if the content body for HMAC signature must be in json format or http_build_query format

Comment: Have you changed the `Content-Type values` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: Yes, I do change that.

Comment: Have you figured out what is the value of `$secret` in `Authorization: $secret:1ZCiCYXXNnIFM8hKZZxrL8jztk+qNMGq17534bbdqd0=`? I think in the headers is the problem, You must input the `HMAC` without format (json/http_build_query  etc.) It must be the actual value

Comment: I'm sure about the $secret cause it was given by the partner. The only thing that I need to do is to compute the HMAC signature.

Comment: I also input HMAC in base64 as it was the requirement of the API.

Comment: Have you tried this? I think is a php variable error. On `"Authorization: $secret:1ZCiCYXXNnIFM8hKZZxrL8jztk+qNMGq17534bbdqd0=",`  `$secret` variable is read as string. try to change that to `"Authorization: ".$secret.":1ZCiCYXXNnIFM8hKZZxrL8jztk+qNMGq17534bbdqd0=",`

Comment: It's working either concatinated or direct. That snippets on the header part is working on my POST request. So I think its not the error